# Unit Test JPA/Hibernate : No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I want to enable Unit Test for my project. I have created the structure as follows.

Directory Structure

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   ├── beans.xml        <-- Works fine in live
│   │       │   └── persistence.xml  <-- Works fine in live
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   ├── com
│       │   │   └── test
│       │   │       └── model
│       │   │           ├── TestEntityManagerUtil.java
│       │   │           └── TestHibernate.java
│       └── resources
│           ├── META-INF
│           │   ├── beans.xml
│           │   └── persistence.xml
```

**CODE**

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <description>TEST Persistence Unit</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://XXX:3306/X" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="X" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="X" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**TestEntityManagerUtil.java**

```
public class TestEntityManagerUtil {
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    }
}
```

**TestHibernate.java**

```
public class TestHibernate {

    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void beforeEach(){
        // Exception occurs here
        em = TestEntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @After
    ....

    @Test
    ....
}
```

**Exception**

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.wellclub.model.TestEntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory(TestEntityManagerUtil.java:12)
    at com.wellclub.model.TestHibernate.beforeEach(TestHibernate.java:24)
```

The test persistence.xml is exploded in `target/test-clases` directory as it is.

Can anyone help me what i would be doing wrong.

Comment: You did not include your application server jars properly. I can tell you the steps to follow if you are using GlassFish, are you?

Comment: After a second look, you are not developing an EE application. So I take my previous suggestion back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please review your JPA implementation library (Hibernate) dependencies in your Maven POM.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
</dependency>'
```

Otherwise add hibernate-entityManager.jar in a non Maven project

#### Edit:

Be aware that the JBoss example you are using is an EE application which uses CDI injection to obtain an EntityManager. A major misconception is to assume that a JUnit tests are operational in EE applications.... No, JUnit tests can neither run the JBoss container nor deploy your project. Yet you can refer to http://arquillian.org/invasion/ and also notice [the JBoss example for an arquillian test](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/bean-validation)

In other words, your JUnit is the SE way of testing an EntityManager and it in not operational in an application server like JBoss.

Comment: I have the same structure like the one used in [Jboss JDF for Hibernate4](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/hibernate4). I do not have enititymanager in the build but have `hibernate-core`, `hibernate-validator` and `hibernate-jpa-api`.

Comment: Yes, got the clue from you and already referring `arquillian`, Thanks.